# Index Seek Operator Cost

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, database-internals

For the [*AdventureWorks*](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks) sample database query below:

```
SELECT 
    P.ProductID, 
    CA.TransactionID
FROM Production.Product AS P
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (1)
        TH.TransactionID
    FROM Production.TransactionHistory AS TH
    WHERE
        TH.ProductID = P.ProductID
    ORDER BY 
        TH.TransactionID DESC
) AS CA;
```

The execution plan shows an *Estimated Operator Cost* of **0.0850383** (93%) for the *Index Seek*:

[image: plan]

The cost is independent of the cardinality estimation model in use.

It is not a simple addition of the *Estimated CPU Cost* and *Estimated I/O Cost*. Neither is it the cost for one execution of the *Index Seek* multiplied by the *Estimated Number of Executions*.

How is this cost number arrived at?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The full cost derivation logic is complex, but for the relatively simple case in the question:

#### Inputs

1. The number of times the operator is executed
   This is the *Estimated Number of Executions*: **504**
2. The cardinality (total number of rows) in the index
   The *TableCardinality* property of the *Index Seek* operator gives this: **113,443**
3. The number of data pages in the index: **201**
   This number can be obtained multiple ways, for example from `sys.allocation_units`:

   ```
   SELECT 
       AU.data_pages
   FROM sys.allocation_units AS AU
   JOIN sys.partitions AS P
       ON P.hobt_id = AU.container_id
   WHERE
       AU.[type_desc] = N'IN_ROW_DATA'
       AND P.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'Production.TransactionHistory', N'U')
       AND P.index_id = 
           INDEXPROPERTY(P.[object_id], N'IX_TransactionHistory_ProductID', 'IndexID');
   ```
4. The density (1 / *distinct values*) of the index: **0.002267574**
   This is available in the density vector of the index statistics:

   ```
   DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS 
   (
       N'Production.TransactionHistory', 
       N'IX_TransactionHistory_ProductID'
   ) 
   WITH DENSITY_VECTOR;
   ```

   [image: density]

#### Computation

```
-- Input numbers
DECLARE
    @Executions float = 504,
    @Density float = 0.002267574,
    @IndexDataPages float = 201,
    @Cardinality float = 113443;

-- SQL Server cost model constants
DECLARE
    @SeqIO float = 0.000740740740741,
    @RandomIO float = 0.003125,
    @CPUbase float = 0.000157,
    @CPUrow float = 0.0000011;

-- Computation
DECLARE
    @IndexPages float = CEILING(@IndexDataPages * @Density),
    @Rows float = @Cardinality * @Density,
    @Rebinds float = @Executions - 1e0;

DECLARE
    @CPU float = @CPUbase + (@Rows * @CPUrow),
    @IO float = @RandomIO + (@SeqIO * (@IndexPages - 1e0)),
    -- sample with replacement
    @PSWR float = @IndexDataPages * (1e0 - POWER(1e0 - (1e0 / @IndexDataPages), @Rebinds));

-- Cost components (no rewinds)
DECLARE
    @InitialCost float = @RandomIO + @CPUbase + @CPUrow,
    @RebindCPU float = @Rebinds * (1e0 * @CPUbase + @CPUrow),
    @RebindIO float = (1e0 / @Rows) * ((@PSWR - 1e0) * @IO);

-- Result
SELECT 
    OpCost = @InitialCost + @RebindCPU + @RebindIO;
```

[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6fe4fadf9f37f451e5c49b8c0a3e6e25)

[image: Result]

Comment: Great work, it's nice to know where the estimated cost comes from, which variables affect it and in which proportion. Is this the mechanic for all SQL Server versions? Maybe a few changes in the constants?

Comment: This aspect of the costing hasn't changed since 2005 as far as I am aware.